# Flask mail sign up page templates takes 10 seconds to load

Tags: templates, flask, optimization, render, flask-mail

Video Link: https://www.loom.com/share/d246f658c9ad442381e4c3f21c155d33
Code app.py

```
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.office365.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'realdomain'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'sample2'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER '] = 'name <email>'
mail = Mail(app)

from modals import *
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
print("Welcome")

def send_mail(email):
    msg = Message(subject="Scrapepilot signup activation",
                          recipients=[email])
    msg.body="Thank you for signing up on Scrapepilot. Please click the link below to activate your account."
    msg.html=render_template('activate.html', email=email)
    mail.send(msg)
```

Blueprint home code:

```
@home.route('/signup', defaults={'page': 'index'}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup(page):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            from app import db
            from modals import User  # User.query.filter_by(email='mahrukh.ayub1@gmail.com').first()#
            user = User(username=request.form['name'], email=request.form['email'], password=request.form['password'],
                        active="0", role="1")
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            from app import send_mail
            send_mail(request.form['email'])
            return render_template('signup.html', data="key")
        return render_template('signup.html')
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

Please check the video above and read the mentioned code. I followed tutorials to write it and I've hosted on IIS server. Website works fine but signup page doesnot load quickly like in php and email is slow as well.
I cannot send mail quickly. Please share how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website probably loads slow because you're sending the e-mail (establishing connection etc.). This may cost a significant chunk of time.

Consider using job services such as [redis](https://redis.io/) with [flask-rq2](https://flask-rq2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to have the e-mail notification send in the background. This will allow you to start/ schedule a job that sends the e-mail in the background and serve the response faster.

A good introduction to job queues for flask would [flask mega tutorial - background jobs](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs).

Comment: yes I try to use redis in python 3 but it says that redis has no attribute Redis or StrictRedis. Why is that so?

Comment: Use rq/ flask-rq and not redis directly. For a solution with redis consult the mentioned guide or (if you've made sure it's reproducible and not you're error) create an issue

Comment: I'm using flask-rq but unable to connect to redis-server

Comment: Are you sure you have setup the redis-sever and configured firewall, flask-rq … config correctly? Otherwise either open an [issue](https://github.com/rq/Flask-RQ2/issues) or open a question for this issue. Debugging flask-rq is out of this questions scope.

Comment: rq is now working well. redis.exceptions.ResponseError: wrong number of arguments for 'info' command is the latest issue.

Comment: @rq.job('high', timeout=60)
def send_mail(email):
    msg = Message(subject="Signup activation",
                recipients=[email])
    msg.body="Thank you for signing up. Please click the link below to activate your account."
    msg.html=render_template('activate.html', email=email)
    mail.send(msg)

high_n_simple_worker = rq.get_worker('high')
high_n_simple_worker.work(burst=True)
scheduler = rq.get_scheduler(interval=10)
scheduler.run()

Comment: above is the code and below is the configuration 
app.config['RQ_QUEUES'] = ['high']
app.config['RQ_ASYNC'] = False
app.config['RQ_SCHEDULER_QUEUE'] = 'scheduled'
app.config['RQ_SCHEDULER_INTERVAL'] = 60

Comment: Redis server version is 2.4.5

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app

Comment: File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app.py", line 64, in <module>
    high_n_simple_worker.work(burst=True)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rq\worker.py", line 511, in work
    self.register_birth()

Comment: File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rq\worker.py", line 295, in register_birth
    if self.get_redis_server_version() >= StrictVersion("4.0.0"):
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\rq\worker.py", line 227, in get_redis_server_version
    self.connection.info("server")["redis_version"]
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 1306, in info
    return self.execute_command('INFO', section)

Comment: File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 901, in execute_command
    return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 915, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 756, in read_response
    raise response

Comment: This isn't related to the original question. Please ipen a separate one for flask-rq problems